# Android LogCat displays partial output logs?

Tags: android, logcat

It has been working well until I changed a smartphone (now HUAWEI Honor 6 Plus). When I start the app, just a few information displayed in Eclipse LogCat. And when the app crashes, there is no exception message shown.

Any suggestions?

The shown debug messages are mostly about `onResume`, `initialization`, `onServiceConnected`, etc., information. The information I want to show with `Log.d()` is not there.

Comment: Inside your Eclipse logcat, set the **Saved Filters** to **No Filters** if you haven't already. Also, try playing around with the different logging methods(verbose, error etc.) in the dropdown to the right.

Comment: use adb logcat>Logs.txt on cmd It will help you to debug issue step by step.Also to get logs in Eclipse just go into DDMS perspective click on device here you will see device info. And this time you will get your logs.One more thing you can try just select All messages here also you can see all the logs or you can add your own filter based on you application package name.